# Unity3d animation events not firing consistently

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an animation that has an event in the middle key frame.

The animation moves a game object on the x and y across the screen in a semi circle.

When the event fires I call animation.Stop().

This stops the game object in the center of the screen to wait for me to swipe and continue the animation or swipe in the opposite direction and have it go backwards. I do this by setting the animation speed to -1.

**My problem is that the object does not stop in the exact same position every time, especially on the reverse, it is always off a little bit.**

After a lot of searching I tried setting the wrapMode to clamp forever, I made sure the event is called right on the key frame and I tried making the time that it starts from, when it's in the middle, is a constant number.

Comment: Can you add some relevant code?

Comment: There isn't anything happening with code really, I added the event though the unity animation window above the middle keyframe and I assigned it to a function in the behaviour script attached to the game object. In the function I am calling animation.Stop(); The animation is 2 seconds long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it better to use a time independent animation system instead of Unity's legacy animation. Legacy animation is heavily depend on frames and it behaves not the same on different device (because of a difference in the frame rate), even on the same device, it can be different due to the current performance of your device. Try something like [iTween](http://itween.pixelplacement.com) or  to do animation or [HoTween](http://www.holoville.com/hotween/) to handle the animation.